# Including subpackages using dune (no implementation provided for modules, but modules are in dune file)

Tags: linker, dependencies, ocaml, dune

While compiling a project with `dune` that uses the [fmt](https://ocaml.org/p/fmt/0.9.0) and [logs](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/logs/) packages , I ended up getting this weird error

```
File "_none_", line 1:              
Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
         Fmt_cli referenced from bin/.main.eobjs/native/dune__exe__Main.cmx
         Logs_fmt referenced from bin/.main.eobjs/native/dune__exe__Main.cmx
         Fmt_tty referenced from bin/.main.eobjs/native/dune__exe__Main.cmx
         Logs_cli referenced from bin/.main.eobjs/native/dune__exe__Main.cmx
```

This clearly indicates that the linker is missing the object file containing those modules.

Problem, I checked, those libraries are installed with `opam` in the current switch, and my dune file contains

```
 (libraries ... fmt logs))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a bit, I realized those modules are contained in separate object files in the opam switch

```
_opam/lib/fmt/fmt_cli.cmx
_opam/lib/fmt/fmt_tty.cmx
_opam/lib/logs/logs_fmt.cmx
_opam/lib/logs/logs_cli.cmx
```

Those are part of opam subpackages (each defined in the `META` file in the same directory)

I needed to add them individually to the dependencies with the following

```
 (libraries ... fmt logs fmt.cli fmt.tty logs.fmt logs.cli))
```